# How to call plenty of hierarchical RESTful APIs simultaneously and efficiently in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, nonblocking

Suppose I've got a RESTful API `/getDivision/dID=?`, the **?** need to be replaced with the actual division ID.

Assuming the dID=1, it return a JSON like below:

```
{
    "division": 1
    "subdivisions": "2,3,4,5",
    "status": true
}
```

The return JSON contains the subdivision IDs of the dID=1 split by commas.

Note that a subdivision also has its own subdivisions and the top division id is 1. So it is a hierarchical API calling.

Now, in Java, I want to collect all the division IDs in a thread-safe collection. How can I run the routine concurrently and efficiently?

I've tried multithreading, but I think it's high performance overhead. Can I do something akin to non-blocking I/O?

Comment: do something akin to multithreading non-blocking I/O, I think it's high performance.

Comment: But the time for a single calling is so short. Multithreading needs context switch, and it's high overhead right?

Comment: *But the time for a single calling is so short.* - If this means that the workload is not heavy that it is worth to create multiple threads, then you can consider using a single thread with a task queue such as single thread `ExecutorService` or you have tried it?